# unreachable code detected

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings

i took this warning,where is the problem?i searched and saw other questions about this error but i couldnt understand whats the problem of this code,thanks in advance

```
 public  PictureBox kingmove(int i, int j)
    {
         return getinfo(i, j);

        if (i < 9)///here is the problem
        {
            grid[i, j] = grid[i - 1, j - 1];

        }
        else
        {
            grid[i, j] = grid[i, j];


        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first statement is a return statement which will leave the rest of the code unreachable.

If you just want to call `getinfo` as part of the logic of `kingmove`, you should remove the `return`. I.e.

```
getinfo(i, j);
```

Assuming `getinfo` returns an instance of `PictureBox`, you may want to assign that to a local, so you can process the output of the method. E.g.

```
var info = getinfo(i, j);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a return statement at the beginning of your method block, so the method will always exit there.

If you wish the other code to run which manipulates the grid, move the return statement after it.

Answer (score 1):

Code written after a return statement will be treated as unreachable since you returned from the function.

And Compiler detects this and let you know as a warning